# some bootstrap methods won't work - rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I use `rails 4` with this in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

The problem is that the `popover` method provided by `bootstrap` doesn't work. At the top of my file, I have

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/vendor/jquery.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/vendor/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

Following this, I set up `config.serve_static_assets` to `false` in my `development.rb`, i ran `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:clean`. But it didn't work. Should I delete my whole `vendor/*` files and `bundle install` again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your link with the `popover` looks something like this

`<%= link_to "popover", "#", :title => "Popover", :rel=>"popover" %>`

Then you would also need to make sure that you are referencing the link to use the `popover` function in your CoffeeScript.

```
jQuery ->
  $("a[rel=popover]").popover()
```

If this still does not work, you may want to try and disable Turbolinks by adding `'data-no-turbolink' => true` to your link.

Comment: I have some `bootstrap_and_overrides.js.coffee`, and inside this `jQuery ->
  $("a[rel~=popover], .has-popover").popover()`

Comment: Btw, I am following some tutorial, and the popover target is supposed to work with this attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"`, isn't it